# Qt and QML for UI and layouts. QtQuick

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout, qml, qt-quick

I know QML is fine for making interfaces in Qt but, how about the layouts of these interfaces?
I want to make an application looking like similar to, for example, spotify. But I want layouts to be "movable" and completely customizable by the user. Is it difficult to make that through QML? Should I better use the usual Qt layout stuff (gridlayout, graphicwidgets, graphic items...) ?

Answer (score 3):

Layout of QML elements works by using anchors attached to other QML elements. You can change anchors at runtime by using Javascript. Building a flexible GUI with QML is possible but challenging because the documentation is sparse in some areas, and debugging is difficult.

Comment: My last point has changed since my post, because if you use QtCreator you can debug qml now.

Answer (score 0):

[Qt Quick Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-index.html) were added in Qt 5.1. They work similarly to layouts in standard widget-based Qt and are usable in Qt Creator.